# Get row number of SQL query

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have this `WP_Query($arg)`:

```
$arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'ma_novel',
    'post_status'=>'fn_publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
);
```

That does this SQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
WHERE 1=1
  AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'ma_rating')
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'fn_novel'
  AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
LIMIT 0,
      10
```

My aim is to get the row number of post with post id `108`.

So far, I have this:

```
SELECT allposts.*
FROM
  ( SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum, posts.*
   FROM
     ( SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
      FROM wp_posts
      INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
      WHERE 1=1
        AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'ma_rating')
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'fn_novel'
        AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
      GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
      ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC ) AS posts,

     (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS r ) AS allposts
WHERE allposts.ID=108
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong to get the row number? I am pretty confident the problem is here:

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum, posts.*
       FROM
```

Or

```
AS allposts
    WHERE allposts.ID=108
```

How do I get the row number of post id 108?

Comment: I will bounty 100 points when this question is eligible for a working solution.

Comment: What result/error are you getting?

Comment: No results are returned. There is definitely something incorrect with the SQL.

Comment: Your second SELECT is referencing posts.*, which doesn't exist. I think you mean terms.* there. Your first SELECT should be posts.* .... WHERE posts.ID = 108.  Not sure if that'll get you the result you want, but it's actually referencing the proper aliases.

Comment: As eisb said, your aliases are messed up. Allposts doesn't exist either. Run each piece in the smallest possible unit and figure out where the records are getting dropped. The RowNumber logic you have looks fine (might not be) but it wouldn't affect the row count.

Comment: @eisb I have updated my question and fixed that typo. But still does not work.

Comment: @Error_2646 I can't figure out how to do the aliases. Can you please demonstrate the approach? Thank you.